# Problem with programmatically JavaScript copy on iOS 12.2

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I have a Phonegap app with the possibility to click a button which will add some text to your clipboard. This has been working up until I upgraded my phone to iOS 12.2.

I have tested on other iPhones with iOS 12.2 and the problem is there too. In the simulator with 12.2 it seems to be working, so I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

I have added the code here so you can see how it's working.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

window.Clipboard = (function(window, document, navigator) {
    var textArea,
        copy;

```
function isOS() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|iphone/i);
}

function createTextArea(text) {
    textArea = document.createElement('textArea');
    textArea.readOnly = true;
    textArea.value = text;

    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
}

function selectText() {
    var range,
        selection;

    if (isOS()) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(textArea);
        selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        textArea.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
    } else {
        textArea.select();
    }
}

function copyToClipboard() {  
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}

copy = function(text) {
    createTextArea(text);
    selectText();
    copyToClipboard();
};

return {
    copy: copy
};
```

})(window, document, navigator);

Comment: I am facing same issue. Please share your solution if  you fix it.